# laravel 4 does not put correct created_at time stamps in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hi i current am working on a project that involves time stamps. A while ago about 9:06 AM here i created a new record but when i viewed the record, the created_at says `2015-12-04 01:06:03`i dont know why the time (`01:06:03`) was advanced. in my controller, here is how i add a record

```
$newPO = new prchorder;
            $newPO->ModuleID      = Input::get('ModuleInfo');
            $newPO->ModuleName    = $moduleName->ModuleName;
            $newPO->Quantity      = Input::get('Quantity');
            $newPO->SystemUserID  = $lsid;
            $newPO->Status        = "Pending";
            $newPO->SupplierEmail = Input::get('SupplierEmail');
            $newPO->Remarks       = "none"; //default
            $newPO->Delivery      = Input::get('date');
            $newPO->Price         = $perMod;
            $newPO->BTax          = $btax;
            $newPO->VAT           = $vat;
            $newPO->TotalPrice    = $total;
            $newPO->save();
```

and in my `prchorder` model here is my code

```
class prchorder extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

protected $primaryKey = 'PurchaseOrderID';
protected $table = 'dbo_purchaseorders';

protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
 }
```

any ideas on what im missing or doing wrong? thanks in advance
is it good to just use something like `$newPO->created_at = /php way to get date time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your default timezone in `/config/app.php`?

Comment: here `'timezone' => 'UTC',`

Comment: What timezone are you in? You can find the proper value for this based on where you are here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php